# An Error in R: When I try to apply outer function:

Tags: r, contour, outer-join

Here is my code:
Step1: Define a inverse function which I will use later

```
inverse = function (f, lower = -100, upper = 100) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1]
}
```

Step2: Here is my functions and their inverse:

```
F1<-function(x,m1,l,s1,s2){l*pnorm((x-m1)/s1)+(1-l)*pnorm((x+m1)/s2)}

F1_inverse = inverse(function(x) F1(x,1,0.1,2,1) , -100, 100)

F2<-function(x,m2,l,s1,s2){l*pnorm((x-m2)/s1)+(1-l)*pnorm((x+m2)/s2)}

F2_inverse = inverse(function(x) F1(x,1,0.1,2,1) , -100, 100)
```

Step3: Here is my final function which combines the above functions (I am sure the function is correct):

```
copwnorm<-function(x,y,l,mu1,mu2,sd1,sd2) {
  (l*dnorm(((F1_inverse(pnorm(x))$root-mu1)/sd1))*
    dnorm(((F2_inverse(pnorm(y))$root-mu2)/sd1)))
}
```

Step4: I want to create a contour plot for the function in Step`enter code here`3:

```
x<-seq(-2,2,0.1)
y<-seq(-2,2,0.1)

z<-outer(x,y,copwnorm)

contour(x,y,z,xlab="x",ylab="y",nlevels=15)
```

Here is the problem comes in, when I tried to apply function outer(x,y,copwnorm), it gives me an error:invalid function value in 'zeroin'. May I ask how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `l`? And `mu1`, `mu2`, `sd1`, and `sd2` for that matter. We can't run your code to see what is wrong. And note I fixed one problem with `copwnorm` as it was missing a parenthesis - hope I got that in the right place.

Comment: Uniroot does not accept a function with returns a non-scalar value, so `(function (x) f(x) - y)` in your inverse function does not work when used with `outer`.

Comment: @Hemmo: It looks like copworm would return a scalar value but there are no default values for the last 4 arguments. I would expect that to be a source of error. Furthermore there is no 'l' value. Failure.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it is a very commom misconception to assume that `outer(x, y, FUN)` calls the function parameter (`FUN`) once for each required pair `x[i]` and `y[j]`. Actually, `outer` calls `FUN` only *once*, after creating all possible pairs, combining every element of `x` with every element of `y`, in a manner similar to the function `expand.grid`.

I'll show that with an example: consider this function, which is a wrapper for the product and print a message every time it's called:

```
f <- function(x,y)
{
    cat("f called with arguments: x =", capture.output(dput(x)), "y =", capture.output(dput(y)), "\n")

    x*y
}
```

This function is "naturally" vectorized, so we can call it with vector arguments:

```
> f(c(1,2), c(3,4))
f called with arguments: x = c(1, 2) y = c(3, 4) 
[1] 3 8
```

Using `outer`:

```
> outer(c(1,2), c(3,4), f)
f called with arguments: x = c(1, 2, 1, 2) y = c(3, 3, 4, 4) 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    6    8
```

Notice the combinations generated.

If we can't guarantee that the function can handle vector arguments, there is a simple trick to ensure the function gets called only once for each pair in the combinations: `Vectorize`. This creates another function that calls the original function once for each element in the arguments:

```
> Vectorize(f)(c(1,2),c(3,4))
f called with arguments: x = 1 y = 3 
f called with arguments: x = 2 y = 4 
[1] 3 8
```

So we can make a "safe" `outer` with it:

```
> outer(c(1,2), c(3,4), Vectorize(f))
f called with arguments: x = 1 y = 3 
f called with arguments: x = 2 y = 3 
f called with arguments: x = 1 y = 4 
f called with arguments: x = 2 y = 4 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    6    8
```

In this case, the results are the same because `f` was written in a vectorized way, i.e., because `"*"` is vectorized. But if your function is not written with this in mind, using it directly in `outer` may fail or (worse) may give wrong results.

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you so much!