# Why doesn't outer work the way I think it should (in R)?

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization

Prompted by @hadley's [article on functionals referenced in an answer today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108045/create-and-call-linear-models-from-list/18109471#18109471), I decided to revisit a persistent puzzle about how the `outer` function works (or doesn't). Why does this fail:

```
outer(0:5, 0:6, sum) # while outer(0:5, 0:6, "+") succeeds
```

This shows how I think `outer` *should* handle a function like `sum`:

```
 Outer <- function(x,y,fun) {
   mat <- matrix(NA, length(x), length(y))
   for (i in seq_along(x)) {
            for (j in seq_along(y)) {mat[i,j] <- fun(x[i],y[j])} }
   mat}

>  Outer(0:5, 0:6, `+`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[3,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[5,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
[6,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
```

OK, I don't have my indices exactly aligned for that example, but it wouldn't be that hard to fix. The question is why a function like `sum` that should be able to accept two arguments and return an (atomic) value suitable for a matrix element, cannot do so when passed to the `base::outer` function?

So @agstudy has given inspiration for a more compact version of `Outer` and his is even more compact:

```
 Outer <- function(x,y,fun) {
       mat <- matrix(mapply(fun, rep(x, length(y)), 
                                 rep(y, each=length(x))),
                     length(x), length(y))
```

However, the question remains. The term "vectorized" is somewhat ambiguous here and I think "dyadic" is more correct, since `sin` and `cos` are "vectorized" in the usual sense of the term. Is there a fundamental logical barrier to expecting `outer` to expand its arguments in a manner that non-dyadic functions can be used.

And here's another `outer`-error that is probably similarly connected to my lack of understanding of this issue:

```
> Vectorize(sum)
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
>  outer(0:5, 0:6, function(x,y) Vectorize(sum)(x,y) )
Error in outer(0:5, 0:6, function(x, y) Vectorize(sum)(x, y)) : 
  dims [product 42] do not match the length of object [1]
```

Comment: your functions are ok, but I'm guessing much slower, so not that great for an R implementation of `outer`; had outer been implemented in C++ instead then the `sum` version would've likely worked

Comment: you're looking for this in your last example: `outer(0:5, 0:6, Vectorize(function(x,y)sum(x,y)))`

Comment: @eddi: I would have upvoted that if offered as an answer.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601359/an-error-in-r-when-i-try-to-apply-outer-function/15751908#15751908

Comment: Your reporter function is possibly helpful, but just wrapping "Vectorize" around a function is not enough to ensure success. @eddi's version is better.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`outer(0:5, 0:6, sum)`  don't work because `sum` is not "vectorized" (in the sense of returning a vector of the same length as its two arguments). This example should explain the difference:

```
 sum(1:2,2:3)
  8
 1:2 + 2:3
 [1] 3 5
```

You can vectorize `sum` using `mapply` for example:

```
identical(outer(0:5, 0:6, function(x,y)mapply(sum,x,y)),
          outer(0:5, 0:6,'+'))
TRUE
```

PS: Generally before using `outer` I use `browser` to create my function in the debug mode:

```
outer(0:2, 1:3, function(x,y)browser())
Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
Browse[1]> x
[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
Browse[1]> y
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
Browse[1]> sum(x,y)
[1] 27          ## this give an error 
Browse[1]> x+y  
[1] 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 ## this is vectorized
```

Comment: A subtlety from `?sum`: `...   numeric or complex or logical vectors`. So `sum(c(1,2,3)) = sum(1,2,3) = sum(c(1,2),3)`

Comment: I like the browser example.  I'll try that with my Vectorize(sum) follow-on Q. (But I don't think that just saying "it's vectorized" is specific enough.)

Comment: @DWin I agree for for the terminology here. "Vectorized" is not the good term here. `dyadic` maybe? feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Just add a link to a new explanatory Q & A on `outer` issue: [“dims \[product xx\] do not match the length of object \[xx\]” error in using R function `outer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317124/4891738)