# Calling outer product without vectorized FUN argument

Tags: r, vectorization, apply

I have a `d`-dimensional function with a vector argument, and I'm trying to compute its values on a regular grid in a simple case `d=2`. It is natural to try `outer` here, which works perfectly, i.e., in the simple case

```
> outer(1:2, 3:4, function(x, y) x+y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    5
[2,]    5    6
```

However, my function does not support natural vectorization. To illustrate, think of something like

```
> outer(1:2, 3:4, function(x, y) length(c(x, y)))
```

with a desired output (obviously, the actual result from the above code is an error)

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
```

My current workaround is something along the lines of `apply(expand.grid(1:2, 3:4), 1, length)`, but that looks a bit clumsy to me. Is there anything as straightforward as `outer` for this case?

Comment: Some [history here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445605/r-outer-matrices-and-vectorizing/21446738#21446738), which links back in the comments to an earlier @agstudy post as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you "vectorize" your function using `Vectorize`:

```
outer(1:2, 3:4, Vectorize(function(x, y) length(c(x, y))))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
```

Or to continue the same idea using `expand.grid`, but with `mapply`:

```
xx = expand.grid(1:2, 3:4)
mapply(function(x, y) length(c(x, y)), xx$Var1, xx$Var2)
[1] 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks for both ideas. I thought it is impossible to wrap my call into `Vectorize`; turns out, it is not.

Comment: You can `Vectorize` dang near anything. It's like "Will It Blend?" :-)