# R double for loop: outer or apply?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, outer-join

I have the following code:

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,8,9)
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
trial <- copy(data)
for (j in 1: ncol(trial)) {
  for (i in 2: nrow(trial)) {
  if (trial[i,j] == trial[i-1,j] & !is.na(trial[i,j]) & !is.na(trial[i-1,j]))  {
     trial[i,j] <- trial[i-1,j] + (0.001*sd(trial[,j], na.rm = T))
    }
 }
}
```

The code perfectly works, but on a larger dataset is a bit slow.
I thought to improve speed by using either the **apply** or the **outer** family. The issues are:

1. I know how to apply a single loop with apply, but not as for 2, especially in this case, where I need to replace single values according to case-specific conditions, with another single value (the lag) plus a multiplier of the standard deviation (which is something I need to compute over the whole column;
2. Except for [this solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460532/r-replace-a-double-loop-by-a-function-from-the-apply-family), I have no experience at all of using outer and vectorised functions instead of loops.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);f <- function(x)ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x);setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, f), ]`

Comment: @Khashaa can u explain me a bit of you solution?  i'm a newbie.. the function is clear, what about the rest? [..] and the .SD

Comment: You can learn about data.table here https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: @Khashaa thank you very much! if you want to put it as an aswer, that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
f <- function(x)ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, f), ]
```

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(x)ifelse(x==lag(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
data %>%
  mutate_each(funs(f))
```

Comment: I can't give you the point because I'm less than 15 unfortunatly

Comment: Sorry I double checked you code and there is a problem: the first observation is turned into a NA

Comment: add `default` value 0(or anything else) to `lag` if you are using `dplyr` as `ifelse(x==lag(x, default=0))`.

Comment: `data.table::shift` has `fill` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,8,9)
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
trial <- data.frame(a,b)
for (j in 1: ncol(trial)) {
# Finds matching rows and add a single row shift in the results
# (diff returns n-1 elements and we want n elements) 
  matching<-!c(TRUE, diff(trial[,j]))
  trial[matching,j]<- data[matching,j]+(0.001*sd(trial[,j], na.rm = T))
}
```

I vectorized the inner loop, this should have a significant improvement on performance.  I didn't test what would happen to the sd calculation if there were multiple matching rows.
I will leave it to others to improve this revision.  The use of data.table could have additional benefits.