# Outer product from list of vectors R

Tags: r, matrix, syntax, distance

I have a list of vectors and I am trying to calculate a distance matrix between them using a custom distance measure. However I am not sure of the best way to go about it:

```
distance.function<-function(x,y){
    return(x %*% y)
}
m<-1:4
values<-list(m,m,m,m,m)
```

What I want is to return something like:

```
outer(values, values, FUN='distance.function')
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   30   30   30   30
[2,]   30   30   30   30
[3,]   30   30   30   30
[4,]   30   30   30   30
```

I have tried using `outer`, but it doesn't seem to like the inputs being vectors, and I have tried `combn`, but don't seem to be able to get the output into the desired format. I'm only intested in the upper triangle of the matrix, ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is actually just a matter of using `Vectorize`:

```
m<-1:4
x<-list(m,m,m,m,m)
mini.test<-function(x,y){
    dot.prod <- x %*% y
    return(dot.prod)
}
outer(x, x, Vectorize(mini.test))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   30   30   30   30   30
[2,]   30   30   30   30   30
[3,]   30   30   30   30   30
[4,]   30   30   30   30   30
[5,]   30   30   30   30   30
```

Thanks to the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601359/an-error-in-r-when-i-try-to-apply-outer-function/15751908#15751908) for helping solve this.